# Poisson distribution probability

Tags: probability

A source of liquid is known to contain bacteria with the mean number of bacteria per cubic centimetre equal to 3. Ten 1 c.c., test-tubes are filled with the liquid. Assuming that Poisson distribution is applicable, calculate the probability that all the test-tubes will show growth i.e., contain at least 1 bacterium each.

My Attempt: $\lambda =3.$ n=10. np=3 $\Rightarrow$ p=0.3

Now, 1-$\frac{3^0\cdot e^{-3}}{0!}$ should give me the probability that all the test-tubes will show growth i.e., contain at least 1 bacterium each.

The given answer is 0.6.

Something is wrong here. I cant wrap my head around this..  :(

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Poisson distribution $P(X=0) = e^{-\lambda}$, i.e. the probability there's no bacteria, hence the probability a tube develops at least 1 bacteria is $1-e^{-3}$. The probability all tubes do it is $(1-\exp(-3))^{10} \approx 0.6$